# Which user entered the stock entry record should be monitored by the administrator

Tags: c#, sql-server-2014

It's for a stock inventory system. the system is created using C#, .net and SQL Server 2014 is being used.

I have a stock entry for "gems"

```
ID | Stock_No | No_of_Pieces | Description | Weight | Cost |
```

Then I have User-manager for which is controlled only by the admin

```
ID | User_Type | User_Name |Password | Create_Date  |
```

There is a grid-view for both entries

How can the admin, monitor which user entered the stock please give me a suggestion how to do that.

This is my login page code:

```
try
{
    SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(" Select * from New_User where User_Name=@USER_ID and Password=@PASS", conn);
    selectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("USER_ID", txtusername.Text.ToString()));
    selectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("PASS", txtpassword.Text.ToString()));
    string UserType = null;
    SqlDataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
    bool rowfound = reader.HasRows;
    if (rowfound)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            UserType = reader["User_Type"].ToString().Trim();

            if (UserType == "Administrator")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Welcome ", "Admin Login", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                Admin_Menu frm = new Admin_Menu();
                frm.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else if (UserType == "StockController")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Welcome ", "User Login", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                Stocks_Gems frm = new Stocks_Gems();
                frm.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
        }

    }

    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(" Invalid User Or Password ", "Login ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    reader.Close();
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("error login " + ex);
}
```

this is my stock entry Gem code:

```
private void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        conn.Close();
        conn.Open();

        string commandText = "INSERT INTO Stock_Gems VALUES(@Stock_Type,@stock_no,@No_of_pieces,@Gem_Type,@Weight,@image,@Cost,@Created_Date,@Updated_Date)";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn);

        command.Parameters.Add("@Stock_Type", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        command.Parameters["@Stock_Type"].Value = Stock_Type.Text;

        command.Parameters.Add("@stock_no", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        command.Parameters["@stock_no"].Value = txtstock_no.Text;

        command.Parameters.Add("@No_of_pieces", SqlDbType.Int);
        command.Parameters["@No_of_pieces"].Value = txtno_of_peices.Text;

        command.Parameters.Add("@Gem_Type", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        command.Parameters["@Gem_Type"].Value = txt_gems.Text;

        command.Parameters.Add("@Weight", SqlDbType.Float);
        command.Parameters["@Weight"].Value = txt_weight.Text;

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        pb1.Image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        byte[] pic = stream.ToArray();
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", pic);

        command.Parameters.Add("@Cost", SqlDbType.Decimal);
        command.Parameters["@Cost"].Value = txt_cost.Text;

        command.Parameters.Add("@Created_Date", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        command.Parameters["@Created_Date"].Value = label11.Text;

        command.Parameters.Add("@Updated_Date", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        command.Parameters["@Updated_Date"].Value = label11.Text;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

        if (cmbStockType.SelectedIndex == 0)
            _lastUG++;
        else
            _lastMG++;
        saveLastNumbers();

        MessageBox.Show("You've inserted successfully!", "Successful Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        this.Hide();


    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

User manager code :

```
try
{
    conn.Open();
    String InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO New_User VALUES('" + combo_usertype.Text + "','" + txtusername.Text
    + "', '" + txtpassword.Text + "', '" + label11.Text + "')";

    SqlDataAdapter execute = new SqlDataAdapter(InsertQuery, conn);
    execute.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("You've inserted successfully!", "Successful Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    conn.Close();

    SqlDataAdapter data = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from New_User", conn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    data.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

    combo_usertype.Text = "";
    txtusername.Text = "";
    txtpassword.Text = "";
    txtcon_password.Text = "";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please clarify your question properly. As far as I understood you wanted to keep track of users entering the information.You can use **global variables** to store **userID** after login which will be available to you until user closes the application.

You can add a class which contains global variables:

```
public static class GlobalValue
    {
        
        public static int userID= 0;
     }
```

After successful login ,you can store **userID** in **GlobalValue**:
**GlobalValue.userID="user id of logged on user"**

and insert into database row or use that **userID** using
**GlobalValue.UserID**

You need to add a column in **stock** table to record userID .

Comment: yes you got what i needed..  where does this global value class goes into ?

Comment: You can keep it inside a folder  or in the root of an application. It doesn't matter actually. If the answer is helpful and clear , please don't forget to mark it as answered.

Comment: You can create a new class. So that it will be easy for you to manage the code

Comment: i stored it in the stock entry

Comment: but its not being detected please help

Comment: i create a column in the stock entry table and the i went to login textbox changed the modifies as public

Comment: After login is successfull , you need to add : GlobalValue.userID=Convert.toInt32(reader["User_Type"]);     Then when you insert into stock table, you need to use: "INSERT INTO Stock_Gems VALUES(@Stock_Type,@stock_no,@No_of_pieces,@Gem_Type,@Weight,@image,@Cost,@Created_Date,@Updated_Date,GlobalValue.userID)";

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163114/discussion-between-mms-mms-and-dot-net-developer).

Comment: i added this code in the GlobalValue.userID = Convert.toInt32(reader["User_Type"]); but still its not working..

Comment: Set value in globalvariable in login form just before showing main form. Use primary key id of user table instead of User_Type in your above comment. That should work fine.